# WCF service spends most of the time in "Sleeping" and "Waiting for syncronization"

Tags: wcf, synchronization, performance

According to Ants Performance Profiler my WCF service spends most of in "Sleeping" and "Waiting for syncronization". As a result I have a bad performance (requests per second)

[image: wcf]

How can I detect these blocks? How can I detect the reason of this behavior?

Comment: what concurrency mode have you set?

Comment: Create a different permon counter for each seperate call, you can then see which ones are taking the longest (should help you identify the ones waiting for synch) - flip side, can you make any of them asynchronous?

Comment: Brijesh Mishra, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall

Comment: Not sure about ANTS but could you give a try to dotTrace? http://devnet.jetbrains.net/thread/290254 just to see if you get same results.